# Will a function be launched when the LiveData paramter's value of the function changed in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The `sortBy` is a LiveData variable, and it is the paramter of the function  `mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort()`.

Will `listVoiceBySort()` get latest result automatically when the value of `sortBy` is changed?

If not, how can I fix the code to get latest result of `listVoiceBySort()` automatically when the value of `sortBy` is changed?

**Code**

```
class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _sortBy = MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(ESortBy.DateDesc)
    val sortBy: LiveData<ESortBy> =  _sortBy

    fun listVoiceBySort(): LiveData<List<MVoice>> = mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(sortBy.value!!)
}
```

Comment: `listVoiceBySort` won't get called again with a new value when the value changes. You would have to subscribe to changes using `observe`.

Comment: How can I fix the code?

Comment: LiveData is only intended for UI components to watch for changes. There's some more fundamental design issue going on here. It looks like maybe this LiveData has an enum value that indicates how the repository should be sorted, or something? Then whatever you're currently using to change this live data should be calling the repository function directly.

Comment: Tried using `observeForever` with a callback so whenever the value is updated , you get a callback and you inturn send a callback with latest result of `listVoiceBySort()` to the caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Transformations.map`:

```
val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> = Transformations.map(sortBy) { mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(it) }
```

or with `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"`

```
val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> = sortBy.map { mDBVoiceRepository.listVoiceBySort(it) }
```

`Transformations.map` returns a `LiveData` mapped from the input source `LiveData` by applying passed function to each value set on source.
It means that `listVoiceBySort` will automatically update its value after changing the value in `sortBy`